# Google Chrome freezes when inspecting WebSQL Database

Tags: javascript, sqlite, google-chrome, web-sql

I'm inserting a new row in a WebSQL Database, which works perfectly fine (the data is accessible later on and is correct), but when I try to inspect the WebSQL Table in Google Chrome's "Resources" tab, the whole Tool freezes. 
The odd thing is: I use literally the same syntax on another table which doesn't cause it to freeze.

The table it freezes on is the biggest table, but with 25 columns it's still well below any technical limits. And, afterall, the data seems to be stored just fine – it's just that Chrome crashes.

Has anyone else experienced that and/or knows about known Chrome bugs causing this? I spent hours looking through my code now, but a) I can't find any mistakes and b) I *literally* use the same structure on another table (with less columns) without any problems.

Edit: Also, right-clicking on anything in the developer tools only opens an empty context menu. Doesn't really look like that's how it's supposed to be either. I'm running Ubuntu, if that's somehow relevant.

Edit2: After continuing to look for an explanation I stumbled across this: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=111468

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be a known bug. Something about infinite loops accidentally being created.